# XML variables and double for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, variables

I'm in stack... Could someone help me?
Here is the situation, i have an .xsl document with the code:

```
           <xsl:for-each select="discovery_channels/channel">                 
                                <xsl:variable name="my-var" select="$my-var +20" />
                                <xsl:for-each select="shows/show">

                                    <xsl:value-of select="$my-var"/>
                                    <xsl:if test="$my-var = substring(continuance/start_at,1,2)">
                                        <tr><td style="vertical-align: top;"><div style="border: 7px solid #002748;">
                                            <xsl:call-template name="picture">
                                                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="@name_show"></xsl:with-param>
                                            </xsl:call-template>
                                        </div></td></tr>
                                        </xsl:if>

                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
```

I want to make double loop, what i mean is: if i have 3 times data of "show", i want to search 3*3 times = 9 times total, becouse i want to search 3 times match "00"string, after that 3 times "01" and so on to "24" (it's hours). I have a veriable which is incremented every 3 times, should be.... but the double for-each doesn't work.

Could someone give me an advice, how i should implemente the idea?
Thanks alot!

Comment: xslt is a functional language, and variables are immutable, meaning once they are set they cannot be changed. You are probably approaching the problem the wrong way. It would help alot if you posted a sample of your input XML, as well as your expected output, as then we can help with the 'functional' approach. Thanks.

Comment: @Jordan, post ur xml and post what you want to get .. will try to help you .. your idea of overwriting variable can be avoided by recalling template using params. And not to blame `<xsl:for-each/>` .. it is as wise as the way you use. :)

Comment: Dear Jordan, You have forgotten to give us some most essential information, such as: 1. The source XML document; 2. The exact wanted result; 3. The rules that the transformation must implement. Please, edit the question and provide all this necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

It's always hard to guess what someone is trying to do by studying code that fails to do it, but my guess is that you might be able to achieve what you want by changing the nonsensical declaration

```
<xsl:variable name="my-var" select="$my-var +20" />
```

to something like

```
<xsl:variable name="my-var" select="position() * 20" />
```